# matching python multiline expression string from a file using grep?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

please note that this is not a python question. I have multiple directories (around 500 directories, called modules) which include a `__manifest__.py` file each. this file is considered as a metadata of the module. the file looks like the following:

```
{
    'name': 'Associations Management',
    'version': '0.1',
    'category': 'Marketing',
    'depends': [
        'base_setup', 
        'membership',
        'event'
    ],
    'data': ['views/views.xml'],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

I'd like to match & extract (using Linux shell only) a pattern which could be as following:

```
'depends': ['base', 'web],
// or multi-line as
"depends": [
    'base',
    'web',
]
```

I am really interested in extracting such information using Linux commands such as `grep` or `sed` or `awk` & I'm not interested in evaluating each file using python interpreter. so I used the following Linux command

```sh
find . -iname __manifest__.py | xargs -I{} grep -H -E "('|\")depends('|\")(.?|\n)*\]\s*," {}
```

however my regex doesn't provide me with multi-line selection. also I am worried about matching more lines that are not needed as following:

```
'depends': [
        'base_setup', 
        'membership',
        'event'
    ],
    'data': ['views/views.xml'],
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GNU grep`

```sh
$ grep -zoE "'depends'"':\s*\[[^][]+]' ip.txt | tr '\0' '\n'
'depends': [
        'base_setup', 
        'membership',
        'event'
    ]
```

- `-z` option will cause `grep` to use ASCII NUL character as separator. So, assuming your input file doesn't have this character, effectively this means the input is read as a single string
- `-o` to get only matching portion
- `"'depends'"':\s*\[[^][]+]'` will match `'depends':` followed by optional whitespaces followed by `[` character followed by one or more non `[]` characters followed by `]`

  - this means any nested `[]` sequences won't be suited for this solution
- `tr '\0' '\n'` to convert NUL character to newline, as `-z` will also mean NUL as separator in the output

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```sh
$ rg -oUN "'depends'"':\s*\[[^\]\[]+]' ip.txt
'depends': [
        'base_setup', 
        'membership',
        'event'
    ]
```

The advantage is that this doesn't depend upon NUL character and doesn't have to read entire input in one go. `-U` is multiline matching option and `-N` turns off line number prefix (which is on by default for terminal output). Also, both `GNU grep` and `rg` support recursive searching.

If your data to be matched is always whole lines, with `'depends': [` in a single line, you could also use `awk`. See [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or) for explanations.

```sh
$ awk '/\047depends\047:[[:blank:]]*\[/{f=1} f; /]/{f=0}' ip.txt
    'depends': [
        'base_setup', 
        'membership',
        'event'
    ],
```